# Is there a way to data protect the defaults file on iOS?

Tags: ios, security, encryption

It seems that the app preferences plist file stored in Library/Preferences is not data protected since I can read it from my locked device with iExplorer. Is there a way to data protect the file?

Also I read somewhere that all apps installed on iOS7 have their files set to protected by default? Is his true, because that would brake apps which try to read from their files in the background when device is locked?

Also I tested it for my own app and the files are not data protected. Or is this not true for Xcode installs?

Comment: For data worth protecting, use the keychain instead!

Comment: You are right. I should not save passwords in the preference file. Still: Why are the Library files not protected?

Comment: `Why are the Library files not protected?` That might be a question only apple was able to answer.